# Онлайн консультант на Asp.net, js и php

Tags: php, javascript, c#, asp.net

Добрый день!
Есть некий сайт написанный с помощью Yii. На данный момент к нему подключен с помощью скрипта на JS онлайн консультант, которых в интернете навалом, и за него платится в месяц +- 500 рублей, дабы работали разные плюшки.

Ну в целях саморазвития, а так же экономии бюджета, хочу написать свой онлайнконсультант для сайта. При этом знаком с C#.

Так как не очень хочу вдаваться в дебри php, возник ряд общих вопросов, на которые хотелось бы получить ответ.

1. В моем понимании это должно быть клиент/серверное приложение, наподобие icq и тому подобных. Т.е. при подключении к сайту, на странице выгружается окошко, которое подключается к серверной части (на определенный ip), на которой уже идет обработка запросов. При этом место оператора будет написано отдельным приложением, без использования браузера. Идея верна?
2. Реально ли с помощь js подгрузить всплывающий клиент, написанный на asp.net, который будет крутится на другом сервере?
3. Или возможно ли к сайту, который написан на php, прикрутить приложение написанное на asp.net?
4. Стоит ли вообще делать такую схему?

Comment: Экономия тут эфемерная. Допустим, ваш час стоит 500 рублей, за сколько часов вы напишете подобный скрипт? А вот в целях саморазвития - вещь полезная.

Comment: Тут дело не в количестве потраченного времени, а именно в саморазвитии. Для души и попробовать себя, потому что хочу кардинально сменить сферу деятельности в сферу ИТ и программирования. Но мне надо понять, реально ли это воплотить в жизнь и не возникнет ли проблема не совместимости данных модулей. В планах уложиться в 3 месяца не сильно активной разработки, но тут уже не угадать, потому что опыта не сильно много.